# Setup node.js on Windows to use with p5.js "Uncaught ReferenceError: cd is not defined"

Tags: node.js

I'm very very very new to this and I'm trying to follow along [this Introduction to Node tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjULmG8fqc8&t=520s) on how to set up Node.js to work with p5.js

The tutorial is for Mac but so far I've managed to do this:

Setup node for windows:

- Download Node
- Install Node
- Open cmd
- Type node + enter
- Type cd to change directory

And here I get this message:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: cd is not defined"

I've tried to work around by open in PowerShell but get stuck there as well. What should I do?
:))

Comment: `cd` is a shell command. Type it *before* you run `node`.

Comment: Thanks!

So I typed it in cmd, and then I got this message: 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\foldername' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Sigh. That tutorial isn't exactly Windows-friendly. What you wa

Comment: I know :'( been scrolling trough the comments on the tutorials in order to find something that could help but no luck there either

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else look for this, here's the solution that worked for me.

In PowerShell:
Ctrl+C once or twice. And instead of running node first, type node + whatever you need to run